# react password eye icon for multiple fields

Tags: reactjs

I have three password fields, each one has a eye icon to let consumer show/hide password,

I am trying with the below code but if i click hide/show for one field then it is effecting to other fields too.

Please guide me with any example of correct the below code

```
class ShowPassword extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      type: 'input',
      score: 'null'
    }
    this.showHide = this.showHide.bind(this);
  }

  showHide(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({
      type: this.state.type === 'input' ? 'password' : 'input'
    })  
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <label className="password">Current Password
      <input type={this.state.type} className="password__input"/>
      <span className="password__show" onClick={this.showHide}>{this.state.type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</span>
      </label>

            <label className="password">New Password
      <input type={this.state.type} className="password__input"/>
      <span className="password__show" onClick={this.showHide}>{this.state.type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</span>
      </label>

            <label className="password">Confirm Password
      <input type={this.state.type} className="password__input"/>
      <span className="password__show" onClick={this.showHide}>{this.state.type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</span>
      </label>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ShowPassword/>, document.getElementById('react'));
```

Below is the jsbin link to play with

https://jsbin.com/homuxoq/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract your input field into it's own component

```
class PasswordField extends React.Component{
  state = {
    type: 'text',
  }


  handleClick = () => this.setState(({type}) => ({
    type: type === 'text' ? 'password' : 'text'
  }))


  render() {
    const { label } = this.props

    return (
      <label className="password">{label}
        <input type={this.state.type} className="password__input"/>
        <span className="password__show" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.type === 'text' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</span>
      </label>
    )
  }
}
```

[Link to JSBin](https://jsbin.com/horayewife/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Another thing I'd like to mention here, is that there is no input type of `input`. Therefore I've replaced it with the valid value `text`.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your password field should have their own state containing a boolean staing if they are hidden or shown.  To avoid code repetitions, make a Component for your passwords.

Working example :

```js
class ShowPassword extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            score: 'null'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PasswordField title='Current Password'/>
                <PasswordField title='New Password' />
                <PasswordField title='Confirm Password' />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class PasswordField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            hide: true
        }
    }

    hideSwitch = ev => {
        this.setState({ hide: !this.state.hide })
    }

    render() {
        const { title } = this.props
        const { hide } = this.state
        return (
            <label className="password">{title}
                <input type={hide ? 'password' : 'input'} className="password__input" />
                <span className="password__show" onClick={this.hideSwitch}>{hide ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}</span>
            </label>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ShowPassword/>, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
$accent: #00BCD4;
$primary: #212121;
$secondary: #727272;

$scoreRed: #F44336;
$scoreYellow: #FFEB3B;
$scoreGreen: #4CAF50;

body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  background: linear-gradient(#607D8B, #455A64);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

form{
  margin: 3em auto;
  max-width: 320px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  
}
.password{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  color: $secondary;
  
  &__input{
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #B6B6B6;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: $primary;
    
    &:focus, &:active{
      border-color: $accent;
      outline: 0;
    }
  }
  
  &__show{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 11px;
    height: 16px;
    right: 0;
    background: $secondary;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: .8em;
  }
  
  &__strength{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 4px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    
    &[data-score="null"]{
      width: 0;
      background: red;
    }
    
    &[data-score="0"]{
      width: 5%;
      background: $scoreRed;
    }
    &[data-score="1"]{
      width: 25%;
      background: $scoreRed;
    }
    &[data-score="2"]{
      width: 50%;
      background: $scoreYellow;
    }
    &[data-score="3"]{
      width: 75%;
      background: $scoreGreen;
    }
    &[data-score="4"]{
      width: 100%;
      background: $scoreGreen;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<form id="react"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are setting state all of inputs get rendered by new type value that you provide to `this.state.type`

you should  remove `type={this.state.type}` for input that you don't want to take effect by show/hide button simply use `type="password"`